# How to export data from ListView to Excel and PDF (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, listview, pdf

I have data in a ListView and would like to export this data with column headers to a new Excel file and a PDF file.

The LV is defined as follows:

```
'listview:
    |  #  |  Col1  |  Col2 |  Col3 | ...
    ==================================
    |  1  |  Val1  |  Val2 |  Val3 | ...
```

I started with this code:

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim objWs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objRange As Excel.Range
Dim i%, j%

On Error GoTo errMsg

Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
objExcel.Visible = False

Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objWs = objWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

With objWs
        For i = 1 To Me.lvlist.ListItems.Count
           .Cells(i, 1) = Me.lvlist.ListItems(i).Text

           For j = 1 To Me.lvlist.ListItems(i).ListSubItems.Count
               .Cells(i, j + 1) = Me.lvlist.ListItems(i).SubItems(j)
           Next j
        Next i
End With

objExcel.Visible = True
objWs = Nothing
objWb = Nothing
objExcel = Nothing
```

But I get an error. How can I achieve my intention? Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I edited the code above and now I'm getting the `error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method`. And the columnheaders aren't export to excel.

Comment: your 2nd loop needs to be subitems count

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here is the following code, which exports the columnheaders with data in an excel:

```
With Me.lvlist
   For k = 1 To .ColumnHeaders.Count
       objWs.Cells(1, k) = .ColumnHeaders.item(k).Text
       objWs.Cells(1, k).Font.Bold = True
       objWs.Cells(1, k).Font.Size = 12
       objWs.Cells(1, k).Interior.Color = vbYellow
   Next

   For i = 2 To .ListItems.Count + 1
       objWs.Cells(i, 1) = .ListItems(i - 1).Text

       For j = 1 To .ListItems(i - 1).ListSubItems.Count
           objWs.Cells(i, j + 1) = .ListItems(i - 1).SubItems(j)
       Next
   Next
End With
```

It works very well :)..however thanks R3UK for your support and effort!

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but you needed to use the `.Count` of the `SubItems` of the specific `Item` :
`Me.lvlist.ListItems(i - 1).SubItems.Count`

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim objWs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objRange As Excel.Range
Dim SubItmCount As Long
Dim i%, j%

On Error GoTo errMsg

Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
objExcel.Visible = False

Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objWs = objWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

With objWs
        For i = 1 To Me.lvlist.ListItems.Count
            .Cells(i, 1) = Me.lvlist.ListItems(i - 1).Text
            SubItmCount = Me.lvlist.ListItems(i - 1).SubItems.Count - 1 '<== argument is not optional .SubItems(..)
            For j = 1 To SubItmCount
                .Cells(i, j + 1) = Me.lvlist.ListItems(i - 1).SubItems(j).Text
            Next
        Next
End With

objExcel.Visible = True
objWs = Nothing
objWb = Nothing
objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: @yuro : Done, please take a closer look at mine too **:p** You are using `ListSubItems` instead of `SubItems` (like in my answer)! ;)

Comment: I saw your answer but when I was trying to take `SubItems` I got an error. `argument is not optional`

Comment: @yuro : try the edit and let me know on which line you get the error

Comment: @yuro : What do you have with `.ListViewSubItems.Count`?

Comment: @yuro : If it's not working, try with `.ColumnHeaders.Count`, it should work like expected. I'm just astonished that we can't find a Count for the Collection of SubItems...

Comment: your code above doesn't work sorry.. I always get `argument is not optional` . Where do I have to define `.ColumnHeaders.Count`?

Comment: @yuro : In there error line, replace `.SubItems.Count` by `.ColumnHeaders.Count`